# MSSQL select count where condition is met across a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing `date`, `employeeID`(int) , and `ShiftWorked` (can be night/day/weekend or evening) . There is a row for each employee and date combination

I would like to construct a query that gives me a count of how many people have worked a night shift in the week before and after each date in the roster period.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date (yyyy-MM-dd)     | CountOfNightshifts(for 1 week either side of date)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

2012-1-1              |  8
2012-1-2              |  12
2012-1-3              |  11
2012-1-4              |  6 
etc                   |  etc
```

I hope this is clear. I have spent days trying to get this to work but I am not getting anywhere.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), [date]
FROM ROSTER
WHERE Shift = night AND [date] BETWEEN DATEADD(D,-7,[date]) AND DATEADD(d,7,[date])
GROUP by [date]
group by [date]
```

This will give me a list of dates and a count of nights on that particular day - not all night shifts in the 7 days before and after the date.

Comment: Please post what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return two columns: the reference (roster) date and the number of (distinct) people that have worked on the night sift seven days before to seven days after the reference date.

```
SELECT tmain.date,
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT taux.employeeId)
    FROM roster taux
    WHERE taux.shiftWorked = 'night'
      AND taux.date >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, tmain.date)
      AND taux.date <= DATEADD(DAY, 7, tmain.date)
) AS [number_of_distinct_people_with_night_shift]
FROM roster tmain
ORDER BY tmain.date;
```

Note 1: Usually I prefer joins over sub-queries, but I guess this solution is easier to read.

Note 2: I am assuming the time component of date values are irrelevant and all dates have the same time (i.e. '00:00:00.00'); if it is not the case, there are more adjustments to be done on the date comparison.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
SELECT
    [date]
    ,count(*)
FROM
    Shifts as s
WHERE 
    s.Date > DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE())
    AND ShiftWorked = 'Night'
GROUP BY 
    date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e88cc/1

a bit more data:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7793/2

If you are only interested in a specific date then you could use:

```
DECLARE @target datetime
SET @target = GETDATE()

SELECT
    count(*) as NightShifts
FROM
    Shifts as s
WHERE 
    ShiftWorked = 'Night'
    AND s.Date > DATEADD(day,-7,@target)
AND s.Date < DATEADD(day,7,@target)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7793/20

but if you have another table that actually has the periods in it (e.g. billing or payroll dates):

```
DECLARE @target datetime
SET @target = GETDATE()

SELECT
p.periodDate
    ,count(*)
FROM
    Shifts as s
INNER JOIN periods as p
    ON s.date > dateadd(day,-7,p.periodDate)
        AND s.date < dateadd(day,7,p.periodDate)
WHERE 
    ShiftWorked = 'Night'
GROUP BY p.periodDate
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc54d/2

OR to get ) when no night shift was worked:

```
SELECT
    p.periodDate
    ,ISNULL(t.num,0) as nightShifts
FROM
    periods as p    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            p.periodDate
            ,count(*) as num
        FROM
            Shifts as s
            INNER JOIN periods as P
                ON s.date > dateadd(day,-7,p.periodDate)
                AND s.date < dateadd(day,7,p.periodDate)
        WHERE 
            ShiftWorked = 'Night'
        GROUP BY p.periodDate
      ) as t
           ON p.periodDate = t.periodDate
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc54d/11

Comment: thank you @ gordatron for your reply - but maybe my question wasn't clear  ( first time asking) . I have modified link slightly [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ded6/2) .this gives me counts for a particular day - not how many night shifts there were in the 7 days either side of the date.

Comment: not 100% sure what you are looking for but added some more options there

Answer (score 0):

You can pull it off by joining the ROSTER table to itself, thereby creating several result rows per employee and day. Otherwise your GROUP BY clause will group the resulting rows from the period you are after into the dates of the original table.

```
SELECT
    r.[date],
    COUNT(period.id)
FROM ROSTER r
JOIN ROSTER period
    ON period.employeeID=r.employeeID
    AND period.shift = night
    AND r.[date] BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-7,period.[date]) and DATEADD(d,7,period.[date])
WHERE
    r.shift = night
GROUP BY r.[date]
```

Comment: Thank You! I swapped the final join clause and where clause - but that may just be because of the way I asked the question